# Python comparing two lists for values

Tags: python

Let's say that i have:

```
usa = ["kebab","pizza", "hamburger"]
uk = ["kebab", "hamburger"]
```

How do i check if uk has all the meals that usa has?

I have tried this:

```
for i in usa: 
if i not in str(uk):
    print("UK doesn't serve %s" % i)
```

This works but only returns on missing item on uk's list. I need to know exactly what is missing. and this meal list might contain around 1000 or more records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set`:

```
usa = ["kebab","pizza", "hamburger"]
uk = ["kebab", "hamburger"]

s1 = set(usa)
s2 = set(uk)

s1.issuperset(s2) # True
s2.issubset(s1)   # False
```

And find the intersection:

```
s1.intersection(s2) # {'hamburger', 'kebab'}
```

Comment: you could also take the difference: `set(usa) - set(uk)` returns `{pizza}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following comprehension way using `all`

```
usa = ["kebab","pizza", "hamburger"]
uk = ["kebab", "hamburger"]

print (all(i in usa for i in uk))
# True
```

Comment: @YakuzaNY: `missing = [i for i in uk if i not in usa]`